# PHP session handling for API of iOS app

Tags: php, ios, oauth, token, backend

I am writing a simple PHP backend. I do not want to transmit the username/password information every time the user is to log-in. Instead, I want to have a token based authentication system.

I do not understand how encrypting a secret key into the token on both the server and client and comparing them should work, or how it makes the system more secure.

1) Is an open source library which abstracts the creation of tokens to use in a settings such as this?

2) What happens when the token expires? When should it expire? Should it be renewed each time a person uses the app and makes a request with an old token?

3) Is it best I bite the bullet and use OAuth? *The backend is mainly for development purposes at the moment and if it's less complex to wrap my own token system I think it would be best.*

Answer (score 3):

My answer probably won't be the best, but it should get you started.

Say you have a user table with fields

```
user_id
user_email
user_salt
user_password
user_vtoken
```

When you first sign up a user, they are prompted to enter their email and a password.

What you should do is salt the password first by generating a random string (eg. hoasyfgq39247t), append it to the end of the password (so say password is "qwerty123", it would become "qwertyhoasyfgq39247t"). Then you hash the salted password with whatever you are comfortable with (password_hash php function, SHA3, etc.) and it should give you a string of a certain length (you can specify length when hashing).

Send the email, hashed/salted password and the salt itself to your server where it creates a user object/row with a unique user_id. You can default user_vtoken to some random string (don't leave it blank upon user creation).

Now when the user logs in for the first time, they enter their email and their password. You should first send a request to your server to retrieve the "salt" attached to the user email. Once you get the salt, append it to the password they entered and hash it with the same algorithm you used when they signed on. That should give you a hashed/salted string. Send the email and the hashed/salted string to your server and do a comparison. If the hashed password matches what you have stored in the database, they are authenticated. Once that happens, have the server generate a new user_vtoken (do this every time a user logs in) and return it to your application.

Once your application gets the user_vtoken, store it somewhere. Now for every subsequent call you make to your server, include the user_email/user_vtoken combo (you can also do user_id/user_vtoken combo if you return user_id on login). If for any reason the authentication fails, make sure you send back the proper error code and force the user to log out of the app and take them back to login screen.

You can store user_id/user_vtoken in persistent memory in your app if you don't want the user to have to relogin on app restart.

**When to reset the user_vtoken**

You will want to reset the user_vtoken on the server side every time the user logs in and every time the user logs out. This will technically log out anyone who is currently logged in to the app since the user_vtoken they stored is no longer valid

**Should user_vtoken ever expire?**

This is up to you. You can set user_vtoken_expiry field every time you generate a new user_vtoken if you want. When a user tried to authenticate with an expired user_vtoken you can force them to re-login. I usually never do this as it's pretty annoying for the users and doesn't really make things that much more secure. You probably do not want to generate a new user_vtoken every time a user authenticates with one as it doesn't provide any extra security and makes your app unusable if your user is logged in from different devices.

**What's with the salting/hashing**

You NEVER EVER want to store actual passwords in your database. There are still an unbelievable amount of idiots out there that store users' actual passwords and then they get breached and all hell breaks loose. In fact, you probably don't ever want the actual password to ever leave the client side. Salting the password before hashing it also prevents people from de-hashing your passwords using pre-compiled dictionaries if you ever get breached.

**More security**

Passing your requests through HTTPS will also lessen your risks of Man-in-the-middle attacks. You can get even more serious and require 2-step authorization (through SMS or extra questions) if you detect a new login from a new device.

**Use Oauth?**

OAuth is pretty powerful, though a bit hard to implement if you are new to this whole thing. Building your own will probably be much easier.

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think to hash the password before it arrived at the backend. It makes total sense to do, but an attacker could still access to the hashed password and use it to log - in. Is the benefit here then preventing harm to users that password-reuse? For now I'm just using a random hash as the token. I remember reading something about a special token that was recommended to be made, specific to a protocol (not sure if it was OAuth or not), but over-all, the system works like you specified.

Comment: Hashing/salting password is mostly used to protect the user's actual passowords, certainly because most people use the same password for a bunch of online services.

Now, yes the attacker could theoretically intercept the hashed password with a man-in-the-middle attack, which is where SSL comes in. It protects all communication between a browser and your server through encryption so no one can make sense of the data even if they intercept it. Another possibility is that someone breaks into your server and finds your users database... in which case you are in serious shit anyways.

Comment: You also mentioned what I assumed is secret/public keys. A secret and public key are mathematically related keys where whatever you encrypt with the public keys can only be decrypted by the secret key. So basically you would make the public key available on your site, encrypt the data being sent out with it, then decrypt it with your secret key stored in your server. This is basically what SSL is (i'm simplifying things alot here), except SSL does it for all communications between your domain and your server. There isn't much of a point implementing this yourself.

Comment: I would go with OAuth, as it will make things closer to "the standard" and it will simplify integrations with other systems/clients/etc. in the future. OAuth2 is way simpler to implement, plus there are many libs doing it for you.

Comment: This is more of a personal opinion, but I always found OAuth2 to be a bit too corporate leaning than original OAuth. Also heard it isn't actually that secure.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    [sessionConfiguration setAllowsCellularAccess:YES];

    [sessionConfiguration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ @"Accept" : @"application/json" }];

     NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession  sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

     NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@home/%@",LINK,str]];  

    // Configure the Request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    request.HTTPBody = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", strSessName, strSessVal] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

     NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                          {
                                              // Handle the Response
                                              if(error)
                                              {
                                                NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please check your internet connection: %@", [error description]]);

                                                  // Update the View
                                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   // Hide the Loader
     [self ShowConnectionError];
                                         });
                                                  return;
                                       }

                                              NSArray * cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:request.URL];
                                              for (NSHTTPCookie * cookie in cookies)
                                              {

                                         NSLog(@"%@=%@",cookie.name, cookie.value);

                                         strSessName=cookie.name;

                                         strSessVal=cookie.value;

                                         NSLog(@"%@=%@", strSessName, strSessVal);
                                       // Here you can store the value you are interested in for example
                                              }




                                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                   ////load your view                              






                                              });




                                          }];

    // Initiate the Request
    [postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: this contains no PHP code, you only showed what to do for the  client side. Thanks though..

Comment: In the client side we need to write only session_start(); after <?php , that will start the php session